# Eventviewer empty logs with English written in Cyrillic Greek

Tags: malware, windows, virus, windows-10, spyware

So a while ago I entered my event viewer on windows 10 and I noticed a bunch of weird entries. They look like they where written in English but with the use of Cyrillic and Greek alphabets. I am running a windows 10 install since the start of the free upgrade.

Has any of you had this experience? Can any of you tell me what it is?

[image: Print screen of weird entries in my event viewer on windows 10]

Comment: Can you copy-paste any of the event log folder names and log names into a comment please? Makes it easier for us to search.

Comment: Run PowerShell, use output from `(Get-WinEvent -ListLog * -EA 0).Logname` for (partial) `Copy&Paste`.

Comment: Thanks to @Jakob, this appears to be [Pseudo-Localization](https://superuser.com/questions/1340277/pseudo-english-looking-characters-used-in-windows-10-insider-preview)